Computer chip in brain, adverts everywhere, hackers save him (black guy)
I'm looking for a movie about a guy who gets run over or something in America where they need insurance money or they will die. Anyway, this big corporation pays his insurance and he eventually recovers from a coma, but with a computer chip in his brain. It's supposed to be a good thing, but its a commercial scam that makes holograms, 3d realistic people-adverts, pop up at him all the time. He's going nuts because the ads keep showing 'till he buys the thing they are selling. Then another pops up...and so on.
Then, he gets helped out by some 'hackers' in a van (boy and girl) but they end up taking him back to their base where an older guy and a Super Hacker called something like 'The Brain' is paralysed tip to toe in a bed but he is still using his brain to hack the huge 'evil' corporation. Turns out he was their best employee and he escaped from them but the chip in his own brain messed him up or something.
Anyway it wasn't a big budget film or anything.
